# How to transform number that include alphabet to a new numerical order in pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert some columns that include number and alphabet at the same time.
I want to convert to simple numerical value such as int.
I don't want to just transform randomly because they are isbn involved. I want to able to match again.
I want to transform that matching as below.

```
d = {'id': [156972, 102154, 214717, 84897, 275220, 165759, 42099, 265749, 130474, 15822], 
      'isbn': ['2842630521', '037570745X','689710879','783547528','786014091','1561581747','553571095','451210220','034540288X','345832710X',]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to transform this way.

```
for id
2842630521 as 0
783547528 as 1
.
.
.
130474 as 9
15822 as 10

for isbn
2842630521 as 0
037570745X as 1 # alphabet involved
.
.
.
034540288X as 9 
345832710X as 10
```

Is there anyway to do this to column?

Optional:  I would also like a way to track back if the number `0` in ***isbn*** column to 2842630521.

Comment: Can you add complete ouput from sample data? Because `2842630521, 783547528...` not exist in `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#random shuffle order of rows
df1 = df.sample(frac=1)

#create mapping dictionary by id
a, b  = pd.factorize(df1['id'])
d = dict(zip(b, a))

#map original column
df['id'] = df['id'].map(d)
```

Comment: is there a way to do it randomly instead of from 0 to 9

Comment: @juggernautmask - what does it mean? random from `0` to `100000` instead `0` to `9`?

Comment: I want it like this 4, 0, 2, 1, 3 instead of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. Like the index is not in order.

Comment: @juggernautmask - answer was edited.